# I've stolen and don't know how to return

Tags: sharia, sin, tawba

I have stolen in the past, years ago, after I hit puberty. I know the owner, I have ability to contact him, I'm close with his family.

But, I don't think he knows about the situation or at most who has done it. He has not been affected by it as it was a cheap item from his stock.

I am too ashamed to let him know about my wrongdoing to him. Now, I'm friends with his family members, share food with some of them, help when I can, and probably have outspent ten to hundred times of the price of the item I've stolen from him in some form or another to his family members.

But I still feel guilty and want to repay properly, but I don't wanna disclose to him that I've stolen from him. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Disclose your sin to him and repent. This is the right way. God forgives and He commanded us to repent and to forgive. So have faith in His Word and do it